# Qt member function of class crashes due to relatively small array. Why?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, memory

I'm creating an application with a class that has a member function called for convenience, run().  Inside run() there are two 400x400 integer arrays that have been called statically.
For some reason the program crashes due to this.  I have no debug information for some other reason which i wont complain about here, but I have tried to dynamically allocate the memory and the same thing happens.  I have a data member 3-d array of 256*256*256 which gives me no problem, so I'm confused as to why this is crashing.

```
int *pointsx = new int [400 * 400]; 
int *pointsy = new int [400 * 400]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) { 
  for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++) { 
    pointsx[400*i + j] = 0; 
    pointsy[400*i + j] = 0; 
  } 
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

D

Comment: You should provide some code.

Comment: 'code'   int *pointsx = new int [400 * 400];
    int *pointsy = new int [400 * 400];

    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++)
        {
            pointsx[400*i + j] = 0;
            pointsy[400*i + j] = 0;
        }
    } 'code'

Comment: I can't figure out how to add code tags correctly.

Comment: I added your code to the question.

Comment: Problems like this are usually due to memory corruption, whose cause and effect are usually far apart. It is very likely that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I can't see anything related to Qt in your question. To clarify your question you need to provide more code.

Comment: Are you using a Qt version that was built with your compiler? I mean if you use one built with a different compiler you could have a corrupted heap because you would have more than 1 independent heap in your application where you can not allocate memory in the Qt dlls and free the same memory in your application. This heap corruption usually does not show up on the delete that causes the corruption. It can show up later in unrelated code and it could certainly be dependent on the size of the allocation.

Comment: I was talking about Visual Studio Qt builds in the previous comment.